# CSV - Read only second table

Tags: python, csv

First of all I'm just starting to programming with Python, so have that in mind :-)

I'm trying to read a CSV file that has 2 tables. All I want to do is to print only the second table. Here is one example of the csv file:

```
id, book, pages
1, Webster’s Dictionary, 1000
2, Tony the Towtruck, 20
3, The Twelfth Night, 144

id, rope, length, diameter, color
1, hemp, 12-feet, .5, green
2, sisal, 50-feet, .125, brown
```

All I want is to print the second table (and if possible without the header).

Right now I have this code:

```
import csv

with open('myOutput-01.csv', 'r') as file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(file)

    next(csv_reader)

    for line in csv_reader:
        print(line)
```

How can I accomplish what I want? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @hansolo It's not me who generates the csv file. That's the problem xD

Comment: @DroidX86 it's one way to not print the first header.

Comment: if you know the headers of the second table it's not that complex

Comment: @hansolo its not people either xD I'm using a raspberry pi to get wireless Data. So the first table is the AP's it detects and second table is for the clients. And I only want the clients table, unfortunately the program generates the .csv file in that way

Comment: @aws_apprentice yes I know the headers for the second table. Can you make me an example how to do it? Thank you

Comment: it seems like you already have the logic of how to read the file, it would simply be a `for-loop` to check if you reach the line with the second headers, once you do you start doing what you want with it, until then just `continue`

Comment: @aws_apprentice the problem is that I'm not getting the comparison working. I did something like this inside the for: `if line == "['id', 'rope, 'length', ...]": print("true")` but the comparison doesn't work.

Comment: that's because `line` is a list not a string representation of a list

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191327/discussion-between-proz1g-and-aws-apprentice).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just skip everything until the header of the second table is reached.

```
with open('myOutput-01.csv', 'r') as file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(file)
    reached_table = False
    for row in csv_reader:
        if reached_table:
            # do stuff
        elif row == 'header of the second table':
            reached_table = True
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer but that doesn't work :/  The problem is that comparision, the `row` is a list not a string. I also tried like this: `elif row[0] == 'id'`but that doens't work either because the previous row it's blank so it throws me an error. Do you know how can I solve this?

Comment: you need to check for equality so make a variable, call it `to_check = ['id', ' rope', ' length', ' diameter', ' color']` and then your line becomes `elif row == to_check`

Answer (score 0):

The best advice would be to separate the tables into csv files. But if you insist on using just one csv file like above, read it like so:

```py
with open('myOutput-01.csv', 'r') as file:
        second_table = file.read().split('\n\n')[1]
        second_table_lines = second_table.split('\n')
        csv_reader = [x.split(', ') for x in second_table_lines[1:]]
        for line in csv_reader:
            print(line)
# Prints :['1', 'hemp', '12-feet', '.5', 'green']
#         ['2', 'sisal', '50-feet', '.125', 'brown']
```